# angular2 rc6 Form validation - Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Angular2 rc6

I have a dynamic form where I click a button and fields are added.  The form starts out empty.  The button adds 4 input fields per row.  So if I click the button 3 times I get 3 rows 4 columns each.

These cases work:

- If I dont add a row and submit no error
- If I add 1 or more rows THEN input data then submit then works

Here is where I get an error:

If I add a row input data THEN add another row I get the below error:

```
core.umd.js:5995 EXCEPTION: Error in 

app/model_exposure_currencies/model_exposure_currencies.component.html:
33:27 caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. 
Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

I am only doing a required validation.

Here is the relevant ts code:

```
cityArray = new FormArray([]);
    myForm:FormGroup;
constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder
        ) {
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
            cities: this.cityArray
        });
    } 


onAddRow(name){

   for (var _i = 0; _i < this.available_loop.length; _i++) {
      this.cityArray.push(new FormControl(name+String(_i+1),[Validators.required]));
   }

}
```

Comment: fyi this does not occur when I enableProdMode().  I just dont know where error occurs in development mode

Comment: If you didn't input and submitted, it makes sense to get 'required' error?

Comment: did you solve this? I have the same error..